# Need To Generate Random Number Between 1 - 3 And Need To Set 3 Variables

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a game with HTML & CSS using DOMS to manipulate the button values/text on the HTML page, to match the values in the JavaScript file.

So there are 3 numbers generated, and they are each assigned to 3 separate buttons on the HTML.

I want to randomize which value is assigned to each button so that the correct inputs aren't in the same button position every time.

I was thinking to generate a random number between 1 & 3 and then return the value and find the other 2 numbers for example

If the random number was 2, the function would determine that it needs to assign the other values to button 1 & 3.

```
//Define  Min Number Range & Main Number & Random Number

var Min = 10;
var Max = 40;

var S1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Max - Min + 1) + Min);
var S2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Max - Min + 1) + Min);

var MainNumber = S1 + S2;
var RandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Max - Min + 1) + Min);

console.log('S1 = ', S1);
console.log('S2 = ', S2);
console.log('Random = ', RandomNumber);
console.log('Main = ', MainNumber);

//Assign Numbers To Elements On HTML

//String Conv

document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = S1;
document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = S2;
document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = RandomNumber;
document.getElementById("p4").innerHTML = MainNumber;

document.getElementById("p1").value = S1;
document.getElementById("p2").value = S2;
document.getElementById("p3").value = RandomNumber;


var VMin = 1
var VMax = 3

var VS1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (VMax - VMin + 1) + VMin);
```

I would expect to be able to return a random number between 1 - 3 and find the 2 missing values example random number is 1, function would be able to determine that it needs to assign values to 2 & 3.

Comment: Maybe you can make a array [1,2,3], shuffle it, and assign the values from 0 to end

Comment: @ChrisLi - great simple solution!

Comment: @ChrisLi, thats a great idea, but how would I shuffel the array, sorry im very new to JS

Comment: @TD3 go through the array, for each element swap it with another random index

Answer (score 0):

you could also just use this code to generate random num from 1 to 3:

```
function randomNum(){
let randomNum3 = Math.round(Math.random()) + Math.round(Math.random()) + 1; }
```